# How to understand vim-latexsuite template expression evaluation?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to build out LaTeX templates for my engineering coursework, and I love the vim environment for editing, so I've been using vim-latex to integrate the two.
I don't quite understand how the templates are being interpreted by vim-latex &/or vim, and google searching has yielded very little.

In particular:
What is the difference between <+ +> and <++>?
What do !comp! and !exe! do achieve?
What languages can I use to do these kind of fill-in-the-blanks processes?

I'm a casual user of vim, so if there's a power-user level concept involved, please point me to where I can read the documentation.

Here's an example of the article.tex template:

```
1 <+ +> !comp!   !exe!
2 %        File: !comp!expand("%:p:t")!comp!
3 %     Created: !comp!strftime("%a %b %d %I:00 %p %Y ").substitute(strftime('%Z'), '\<\(\w\)\(\w*\)\>\(\W\|$\)', '\1', 'g')!comp!
4 % Last Change: !comp!strftime("%a %b %d %I:00 %p %Y ").substitute(strftime('%Z'), '\<\(\w\)\(\w*\)\>\(\W\|$\)', '\1', 'g')!comp!
5 %
6 \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
7 \begin{document}
8 <++>
9 \end{document}
```

Comment: I'd suggest to use a generic template solution like [ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) which was designed to provide templates for *any* language. It includes lots of templates for all sorts of languages (including latex) and it's very easy to extend and create new snippets.

Comment: I'd second @Marco's suggestion. Have a look at [vim snippets](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets) for an overview of vim general purpose snippet engines.